# Open a PDF-document based on input from a text field

Tags: php, html

I would like to have a script (HTML or PHP) which will open a document from our network based on the input from a text field.

So, when I fill in the text `123456789` the document `123456789.PDF` from the location `\\server\documents\` needs to be opened.

Comment: have you tried anything? How would you like to display it? Could it be by triggering a click on hidden link to your desired file?

Answer (score 0):

You want to open the document in the user browser?

You can do it with some Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function go()
 {
   document.href = '\\server\documents\' + document.getElementById('toto').value + '.PDF';
 }
</script>

<input type="text" id="toto" />
<button onclick="go()">Open me</button>
```

This is the same if you want to open the file with PHP, just concat the strings and use `file_get_contents`.